# Why eslint doesn't show typescript errors?

Tags: typescript, frontend, eslint

Why eslint doesn't show typescript errors in a console? If I understand correct eslint should show typescript errors in a console. If is not true please help me understand how correct check eslint errors with typescript ?

I have a .eslintrc.json config.

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["prettier", "react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"] }]
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

My babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "corejs": 3,
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "modules": false,
        "loose": true,
        "targets": ["last 1 version", "> 1%", "not dead", "not IE 11", "not ie_mob 11"],
        "debug": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

Script in my package.json

```
"lint:es": "eslint --ext=.js,.ts,.tsx src"
```

I general i want to add typescript end linter check when i run my webpack devs erver.

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify the project "tsconfig.json"

```js
 "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "ecmaFeatures": {
          "jsx": false
        },
        "project": ["./tsconfig.json"],
        "tsconfigRootDir": "./"
    }
```

then on your package.json add:

```
"lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
```

and last on your `tsconfog.json` you need

```js
"compilerOptions": {
....
},
"include": [
"./src/*.ts",
"./src/**/*.ts",
"./src/**/**/*.ts",
"./src/**/**/**/*.ts",
"./src/**/**/**/**/*.ts",
"./src/**/**/**/**/**/*.ts",
],
"exclude":[
"./node_modules/"
]
```